# Using values selected by JQuery datepicker from code-behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery-ui-datepicker, code-behind

I am building an ASP.NET website, and in the aspx markup page i put in a JQuery datepicker.
I also set default values, and on the FE side it looks ok, the text box is always populated with the selected date.
However when im trying to use the text values in the text box, it acts like there's nothing there.

This is my JS function in the ASPX page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        //console.log($("[id$=txtFromDate]"));
        //console.log($("[id$=txtToDate]"));
       $("[id$=txtFromDate]").datepicker();
       $("[id$=txtToDate]").datepicker();

       //init date format
       $("[id$=txtFromDate]").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' });
       $("[id$=txtToDate]").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' });

       //init default date
       var FromDate = new Date();
       FromDate.setMonth(FromDate.getMonth()-1)
       $("[id$=txtFromDate]").datepicker('setDate',FromDate);
       $("[id$=txtToDate]").datepicker('setDate','today');
   });
```

How can i work with the datepicker from the code-behind C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
 $("[id$=txtToDate]").datepicker('setDate','today');
```

with

```
 var Today = new Date();
 $("[id$=txtToDate]").datepicker('setDate',Today);
```

and then in code behind you can use this code

```
Request.Form["txtToDate"]
```

"txtToDate" is your input box Name and don't use input box id;

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.
I tried in the code-behind:
    PickFromDate.Text = Request.Form["txtFromDate"];

But still its sending the PickFromDate.Text as empty string

Comment: btw not sure how relevant it is, but the controller connected to the datepicker isn't an input type , but asp.TextBox controller

Comment: Check TextBox name and Check all  Request.Form parameters that send from the client in HTTP Header.To make sure you don't make mistakes.

Comment: Found it! The HTTP header parameters list this as "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtFromDate" instead of "txtFromDate"
Any idea why?
The TextBox controller is inside a table

Comment: Asp.net form determines the name of items that is runat="server".  txtFromDate is the only id of your box.